# scalable security data model

Tags: database-design, architecture, data-modeling

In the past i would use the following simple data model to implement security into my applications. I would have an ***implicit deny, explicit allow and explicit deny*** which the later could overide the one preceding it.

[image]

The problem i'm facing now is that my current application needs to be scalable to tens of millions of records. In the data model above, for each record i could possibly have many ACL entries. So if my records table (acltest_uspaceData) has 10 million rows my acl security tables could have a lot more.

**Is this an appropriate data model for the amount of records we plan on storing?** If not,  **What can i do to this datamodel to make it scalable?**

I'm using PostGIS as a Database.

## Update - Rules:

1. It's should be implied that nobody has access to anything if there
   are not security associations made for that record.
2. To allow user or group access, you must explicitly Allow them to access
   that record via some security association.
3. To deny someone access who already has access via group membership,
   you must explicitly deny that person access to that record via a security association.

Comment: What's the difference between "implicit deny" and "explicit deny"? Does it "reconcile" the conflicts between roles and users? If so, what are the exact rules? I'm just wondering whether **both** `allowed` fields are necessary...

Comment: Also, is it common to have a lot of records with _same_ permissions?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Thanks for your comment. Implicit deny means if there aren't any security entries for a record, then nobody can access them. It's implied that nobody has access to anything unless you explicitly allow them to access it. Then the explicit deny is used to override explicit allows. So when i want to give a group access to a record except for 1 person in that group, i can explicitly allow the group and explicitly deny that one member.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic As for your next question, yes, it is common to have many people with the same permissions.

Comment: Actually, my question about permissions was in the opposite "direction". Let me restate it: are there many rows in `acltest_uspaceData` that have same permissions (i.e. that are connected to the same set of users and groups, and in the same way)?

Comment: Yes, there are many rows with the same permissions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your security rules, the `acltest_role_acl.allowed` looks redundant - if a role ACL entry is present then `allowed == true` can be implied. Unless, of course, you actually want the ability to "revoke" whole groups and not just individual users.

Other than that, your model looks good and you should concentrate on storing it efficiently in the database.

In case your DBMS supports it, it is probably a good idea to store ACLs as a [clustered table](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index):

- If you want to efficiently answer the question "which ACL entries does the given record have", then the order of PK columns in the clustered table should be `{record_id, user_id}` for user ACLs and `{record_id, role_id}` for role ACLs.
- If you want to efficiently answer the question "which ACL entries does the given user or role have", then the order of PK columns should be reversed (i.e. `{user_id, record_id}` and `{role_id, record_id}`).
- If you want to efficiently answer *both* questions, you'll need an index in both "directions". Unfortunately, secondary indexes are expensive in clustered tables, so you might consider using a heap-based table and two ordinary indexes in this case.

If your DBMS supports it, you could compress the leading edge of the clustering index (under Oracle, this is known as COMPRESSED INDEX ORGANIZED table). This would remove some of the redundancy stemming from repeated ACLs (from your comments: "it is common to have many people with the same permissions" and "there are many rows with the same permissions").

---

On the other hand, *if* you are primarily worried about storage cost (and/or use a DBMS that does not support compression), but don't mind increased complexity and potential performance impact, you could consider something like this:

[image]

Since many records share the same ACLs (as per your comment), this model would avoid most of the repetition.

For example, if N records have the same 5 ACL entries:

- Old model would require N*5 ACL entry **rows**.
- The new model would only require 6 rows + N **fields**, which is much cheaper storage-wise (6 rows = 5 ACL entries + 1 group, and the field is: `acltest_uspaceData.acl_group_id`).

The problem is: when you insert a new record, how do you find the "matching" ACL group? This could be solved roughly like this, but would not be terribly efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM acltest_aclGroup
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT user_id, allowed
        FROM acltest_users_acl
        MINUS -- Or EXCEPT, depending on the DBMS.
        SELECT user_id, allowed
        FROM <user_acl_tmp>
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT user_id, allowed
        FROM <user_acl_tmp>
        MINUS
        SELECT user_id, allowed
        FROM acltest_users_acl
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT role_id
        FROM acltest_role_acl
        MINUS
        SELECT role_id
        FROM <role_acl_tmp>
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT role_id
        FROM <role_acl_tmp>
        MINUS
        SELECT role_id
        FROM acltest_role_acl
    )
```

First, you create a temporary table for user and role ACLs (`<user_acl_tmp>` and `<role_acl_tmp>`), then insert the ACL entries the new record should have into them, then execute the above query which searches the existing ACL groups for set equality with temporary ACLs.

Comment: Brako, Thanks for your answer (+1). It might take me a few days to get back on this portion of the project. But i will analyze this then carefully and test it out. Looks very promising! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an authority on this subject, but someone I know who develops cloud platform services for one of the largest CDN providers in the country strongly favors [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) in cases where scalability is a concern.  I'm not sure whether it will handle your ACL requirements, but a little research should tell.

Comment: Thanks, but not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a database design not directory services. But thanks anyway.